# Time is not showing right in Excel when formulated correctly

Tags: excel-formula

This is my formula.

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,Ticket_Import!B:B,Ticket_Import!T:T/86400,"Empty")
```

When I run this without the division it shows the actual number in cell Ticket_Import!T:T, which is 172855.

Now if we use the basic math of 172855/86400 should come out to be 2.044... which would be 2 days and 44 minutes?

But when I format it to show time, it shows it as 0:00:55.

When I try to put the cell as time it shows up as 00:00:00, or Jan-00

Now, I am pretty good at running excel scripts but I must be overthinking this.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

My cells are formatted for hh:mm:ss btw.

Comment: You seem to state 2 different outputs when the cell is formatted as time. Which is which? What format did you use? Try `[h]:mm` as that is needed to avoid doing modulo 24 on hours. Also, aren't your cell references to entire columns? That seems like it shouldn't work, or at least not necessarily how you intended. A minimal reproducible sample is very desirable.

Comment: I get `2.000636574` for `=172855/86400` which is 2 days and 55 minutes

Comment: @ScottCraner correct, and when I try to format the cell which this formula is under, to show that, it shows 00:00:00.  The output doesn't match the answer.

Comment: @underscore_d The forumula where the cell is showing the data is formated for hh:mm:ss

The cell where the data is pulled from, is formatted as text.

Comment: @underscore_d the XLooup allows the entire column to be refrenced at once.  Which would be easier to manually changing the cells to refrence over 20K cells...

Comment: When I format the cell it shows `00:00:55`  Are you sure you are formatting correctly? what language is you local settings?

Comment: @ScottCraner 00:00:55 is not 2 days and 55 minutes... that's my problem. That shows up as 55 seconds...

Comment: @ScottCraner English?

Comment: what do you want to show? `hh:mm:ss` will only show the time portion.  How do you want to handle the day portion?  what would your ideal output be given that input?

Comment: Wait, I just got what you want and our disconnect.  You should be dividing by `1440` not `86400`  if `172855` is the number of minutes.

Comment: @ScottCraner those are seconds as far as I know... because to give you an idea... this is more data I didn't share because it's in other fields. 

It was created on: 2020-05-16T15:40:38+00:00
It was closed at: 2020-05-18T15:41:33+00:00

Which is two days, and change? So if you can figure out where I have failed it would be greatly aprpeciated.

Comment: you are right it is 2 days and 55 seconds different which brings us back to the `00:00:55` being the correct time portion of the difference, and again asks, "What are you expecting to see?"

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, you helped, I figured out what I needed to do.  dd:hh:mm:ss  it came out fine on my end now.

Comment: Just remember that `dd` returns the day of the month and as such if the days go over 30 it will start at 1 again.

Comment: @ScottCraner if what we do, a ticket goes over 30 days, we have other issues.